# Excel - Colouring items in dropdown list

Tags: microsoft-excel, dropdownlist

I created a dropdown list on excel but I have lots of items in it. I want to categorize the items in that list and make the similar ones appear in the same colour.
All I could find so far was how to colour the cell that contains the drop-down list based on the item I choose (using conditional formatting) but how do I actually colour the items in the dropdown list?

Comment: How about this method? https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f13f9e51-c599-452e-9ca8-78866a1e15d7/looking-to-have-a-text-pull-down-that-puts-an-image-in-the-same-cell-as-selection-is-made?forum=excel

Answer (score 0):

> how do I actually colour the items in the dropdown list?

You **can not do it with built in drop down**.

If it's really a must have then you might develop your own form with such a list, but that point it'd be really complicated.

Comment: The most easiest is,,, add list (range of cell) to Drop Down, then apply either different colors to each item or any one color, using Conditional Formatting.

Comment: @RajeshS "how do I actually colour the items in the dropdown list?"

Comment: @ Máté Juhász ,, to apply colors,, put Drop down data in Range,, the apply either color to them or conditional format like Green to OK,, Red to BAD,, Yellow to AVERAGE then use that Range as list to DD,, !

Comment: ok, i'll try that, thank you!

Comment: @RajeshS: I've tried your suggestion, but it doesn't work, maybe you could post some screenshots?

Comment: @MátéJuhász,, I've posted the method ,, hope this works for you and OP too .

Answer (score -1):

*This solves the issue:*

**Method 1:**

*Below is non VBA (Macro) method, can be used with Drop down on Sheet.*

[image]

---

**How it works:**

- Create source data in `H126:H128`.
- Select cell `I126`.
- Hit **V**alidation from **D**ata TAB.
- Pick `H126:H128` as List Source, finish with **O**k.

[image]

---

- Select cell `I126` & from **H**ome TAB hit **C**onditional Formatting.
- Then **N**ew Rule, now select **F**ormat only cell contains.
- For **R**ule, select option Cell value, Equals to & cell $H$126.

[image]

---

- Apply an appropriate cell formats & finish with **O**k.
- Repeat steps 5 to 8 for other colors.

---

*Start clicking the Drop Down you get color effect.*

---

**Edited:**

**Method 2:**

**:Caveat:**

*Since apply color directly to the Drop down is not possible therefore the only option left is the MACRO (VBA code), by using the Combo box.*

*This comprised VBA macro and Combo box, the Active X control.*

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

**How it works:**

- To Open VBA editor, either press **Alt+F11** or **R**ight click the Sheet   TAB.
- From the **P**roject explorer windows, **D**ouble click the **T**hisWorkbook Icon.
- Copy & Paste this code as standard module.

---

```
     Private Sub Workbook_Open()

     Application.EnableEvents = False


    With Sheet1.ComboBox1
        .AddItem "Fruits"
        .AddItem "Vegetables"
        .AddItem "Soaps"
        .AddItem "Beverages"
    End With

      Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub
```

**N.B.** *You may put your own item's list (are editable).*

---

- From **F**ile Menu click **C**lose & Return to Microsoft Excel or hit **Alt+Q**.
- Now at the Sheet, from **D**eveloper TAB hit **D**esign and from left to it, click **I**nsert.
- From **A**ctiveX controls select **C**ombo box Icon and draw on sheet at suitable place.
- **R**ight click the **C**ombo box and from pop up menu hit **P**roperties.

[image]

- Set Font color and Link cell property.

**N.B.** You may set Font color and the Lined cell as you wish (are editable).

- Now **C**lick the **C**ombo box and for it's **C**hange event **C**opy & **P**aste this code.

---

```
    Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

    Cells.Range("A6").Select
    Cells.Range("A6").Font.ColorIndex = 3       

    '=== below shown Font Bold, Name & Size properties are optional you may skip.

     Selection.Font.Bold = True

     With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .Size = 11
     End With
     End Sub
```

---

- Press **Alt+Q** to Save & return to the Sheet.
- Finally from the **D**eveloper TAB **C**lick again the **D**esign button to deactivate it.

**N.B.**

- *Save the Workbook as **M**acro Enabled (.xlsm).*
- *Now the Combo box is ready to works.*
- *Check the Screen Shot above.*

Comment: "All I could find so far was how to colour the cell that contains the drop-down list based on the item I choose (using conditional formatting) but how do I actually colour the items in the dropdown list?"

Comment: @MátéJuhász,, now check the edited part,, I'm sure this is what you and others are looking for,, hope you up vote twice this time ☺

Comment: "I want to categorize the items in that list and make the similar ones appear in the same colour." - you're approach applies the same colour for everything.

Comment: @MátéJuhász,, this code also can be extended to apply different category,,, putting IF between line 2 & 3 !!